# How to delete two items in a row in a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void delete_double (LN<T>*& l) {
    if (l == nullptr)
        return;

    LN<T> *p = l;
    while ( p -> next != nullptr && p -> next -> next != nullptr)
    {
        if (p -> value == p -> next -> value) // the current value is equal to the next value in the linked list 
        {
            if (p == l)                     // when the first two values are the same                                        // not sure if it is correct
            {
                l = l -> next -> next;
            }
            else                            // Problem should be here
            {
                LN<T> *to_delete = p;       //  Also tried this (doesn't work)
                p = p->next;
                delete to_delete;           //  LN<T>* to_delete = p;
                                            //  LN<T>* to_delete2 = p -> next;
                LN<T> *to_delete1 = p;      //  l = to_delete2 -> next;
                p = p->next;                //  delete to_delete;
                delete to_delete1;          //  delete to_delete2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            p = p-> next;
        }
    }
}
//  Image below is my output
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlNL2.png)

Hi, I am writing a function that would delete two values in a row in a linked list if the two values are the same. My code seems to stop working when the input is something like "1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 3 -> 4 -> nullptr".(the output should be 1 -> 2 -> 4 -> nullptr). It exits without giving me any error. And I went through the debug line by line, It just suddenly exits and showed "variables are not available".

I am guessing it is the problem that when I delete p, the l points to garbage, which causes the problem. So I tried a different way to make l point to to_delete -> next. But it still does not work.

I have tried so many hours to fix it and the debug won't even help. Can someone please help? Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh I see. Also, when you delete an item you need to modify the next pointer of the item preceding it.

Comment: Would you delete all values which appear twice? or is it just 1 pair?

Comment: @lykdog *and the debug won't even help* -- Seems like you should first work this out on paper using boxes for the data and lines for the links, before you write any code.  Then debugging would be just a matter of seeing where your code goes against what you have on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have simplified the code above, the logic you have above also wont help you remove multiple duplicates. So lets look at the code below and dissect it:

```
   void delete_double(LN<T>*& l) {

        if (l == nullptr)
            return;

        LN<T> *p = l;
        LN<T> dummy(0);
        dummy.next = l;
        p = &dummy;

        LN<T> *temp;
        LN<T> *duplicate;
        LN<T> *prev;

        while (p != nullptr && p->next != nullptr)
        {
            temp = p;
            while (p != nullptr && temp->next != nullptr)
            {
                if (p->value == temp->next->value)
                {
                    duplicate = temp->next;
                    temp->next = temp->next->next;
                    delete duplicate;

                    duplicate = p;
                    prev->next = p->next;
                    p = prev;
                    delete duplicate;

                    temp = p;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
            prev = p;
            p = p->next;
        }

        l = dummy.next;
    }
```

There seems to be a need for a dummy node at the start because if we have 1 -> 1 - > 2 we need to delete the first two and point to the correct head which is a 2. In order to avoid this confusion is better to keep a dummy node at the start and at the end just set the output of your list to be p = dummy.next, which is the actual start of your list.

I have defined some temporaries, `temp` and `duplicate`, temp to help me navigate further in the list and duplicate to hold the duplicate value, move the pointer to next and delete the node. `prev` is the previous pointer to the node just before the duplicates.

Each node in the list, `temp = p` I move forward until looking for the adjacent match `p->value == temp->next->value` if there is a match I delete the current node and the one I found ahead of it. I use the `prev` tracker to restore the order of the list by correctly setting its `next`, else I break from my inner loop and move on to the next value, the outer loop `p = p->next`.

I am not sure about your `LN<T>` struct so I have gone ahead with what I think it is.

[Demo Link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/433d646aaad4aef8)

Comment: That should be an easy fix, I misunderstood the original, sec

Comment: Check if this passes your test cases and I will update the explanation in the meantime

Comment: It passes 1->1->2->3 as well. Let me add a link to a demo

Comment: @lykdog check the answer I have added a demo link output is as expected for 1->1->2->3 you get 2->3 you can play around with it in the editor it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

Before or after you delete p, the item before p should point to the item after the two deleted items. Otherwise, the link list will broken.

Furthermore, for the while-loop, you may only stop when you arrive the last item. Otherwise, if the last two items are the same, you cannot correctly delete it.

Here is my version. I used a dummy item to point to the item before the current compared item. Notice this cannot deal with 3 items in a row.

```
void delete_double (LN<T>*& l) {
    if (l == nullptr)
        return;
    LN<T> *dummy = new LN<T>;
    dummy -> next = l;
    while ( dummy -> next != nullptr && dummy -> next -> next != nullptr) // search until the last but two item
    {
        if (dummy -> next -> value == dummy -> next -> next -> value) // the current value is equal to the next value in the linked list
        {
            dummy -> next = dummy -> next -> next -> next;  // link the item after dummy to the item after the deleted items         
        }
        dummy = dummy -> next; // move dummy to the next, notice that this cannot deal with 3 items in a row
    }
    return;
}
```